What's the Benchmark for Displaying Percentage Gain/Loss on the Yahoo Finance App?
Apologies for the extremely noob question as I am getting started with the concepts of stocks, trading etc.
I am using the yahoo finance to monitor a few assets and here is a screenshot.

For context, I live in Singapore (UTC+8h). So the primary question is, when the watchlist shows me an asset is up 2.8% (hypothetically), what timeframe does it refer to? Some possibilities I can imagine

12 am (Singapore time) till now, as the app knows I am in this time zone?
12 am of the the trading location (I don't know if there is an established term), such as US east coast time for S&P500 etc.?

Also, stock indices trade in a finite time window (9 am-5pm) of the specific location on every weekday? So they have a daily closing price?
But what's the closing price for Gold, as an example? Does not it trade for the entire working week, i.e. from 9 am Monday on the most advanced timezone, to 5 pm Friday on the most lagging timezone (whichever they are)? So we have only weekly closing price?
Then, my understanding is bitcoin trades are on 24x7, so there is not even a closing price as such, to calculate a percentage against?
Maybe I am thinking too much, but basically trying to find the correct way to interpret these percentage figures on the app for these different cases. Any help would be appreciated.
